# why doesn't chown work in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, chown

My Dockerfile creates a directory, chown's it, and then lists the directory afterwards.  The directory is still owned by root.  Why is that?

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:precise
RUN useradd -d /home/testuser -m -s /bin/bash testuser
RUN mkdir -p /var/local/testrunner/logs
VOLUME ["/var/local/testrunner/logs"]
RUN grep testuser /etc/passwd
RUN grep root /etc/passwd
RUN chown -R testuser:testuser /var/local/testrunner/logs
RUN ls -ld /var/local/testrunner/logs
```

Here is the output from "docker build":

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 10.24 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu:precise
 ---> ab8e2728644c
Step 1 : RUN useradd -d /home/testuser -m -s /bin/bash testuser
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 640f12671c86
Step 2 : RUN mkdir -p /var/local/testrunner/logs
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bf7756fd5b1f
Step 3 : VOLUME ["/var/local/testrunner/logs"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 65c73ee76c20
Step 4 : RUN grep testuser /etc/passwd
 ---> Using cache
 ---> db72fff0b965
Step 5 : RUN grep root /etc/passwd
 ---> Running in ebff78df7a9a
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
 ---> ead0ff704a59
Removing intermediate container ebff78df7a9a
Step 6 : RUN chown -R testuser:testuser /var/local/testrunner/logs
 ---> Running in c925f67b2ab4
 ---> 253132be935e
Removing intermediate container c925f67b2ab4
Step 7 : RUN ls -ld /var/local/testrunner/logs
 ---> Running in 978bc66aa47e
drwxr-xr-x 2 root staff 4096 Oct  1 15:15 /var/local/testrunner/logs
```

Docker version 1.2.0, build fa7b24f

The host runs Ubuntu 12.04, but with a 3.13.0-36-generic kernel.

Comment: For issues with onership after COPY, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766665/how-do-i-docker-copy-as-non-root

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Answering my own question: it's declared to be a volume.  If you take out the VOLUME instruction, the chown takes effect.

What's more, if you declare the volume *after* running chown, the chown settings remain in effect.

Comment: "If you declare the volume after running chown, the chown settings remain in effect"

This just answered something that's had me stumped for two days. Thank you!

Comment: @user100464 I wonder if there is a reasonable explanation for this quite odd behavior. It seems you only figured this out by trial & error. Or is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Answering myself: The explanation here made sense to me http://container-solutions.com/2014/12/understanding-volumes-docker/

Comment: If I mount volume to container,  perm switch back to `root:root`. I use `CMD chown -R user:user /path/to/dir && gosu user command` to solve this problem.

Comment: An important point from that article above: "[When `VOLUME` is specified after a `RUN` command that modifies the volume], docker is clever enough to copy any files that exist in the image under the volume mount into the volume and set the ownership correctly. **This won’t happen if you specify a host directory for the volume (so that host files aren’t accidentally overwritten).**"

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question and saving some of my hair

Comment: Updated URL for explanation linked by @MichaelHärtl is: https://blog.container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker

Comment: Tremendous!   A double answer!

Comment: I don't declare any VOLUME on my dockerfile and still have this issue... :-(

Comment: @fccoelho - found any solution?

Answer (score 10):

This blog http://container42.com/2014/11/03/docker-indepth-volumes/ explains this behaviour in detail.

Each instruction in the Dockerfile creates a new container. The instruction make some changes to this container and becomes a new layer. The changes made to "/var/local/testrunner/logs" before VOLUME instruction were made to the actual container filesystem. However, after VOLUME instruction, the directory "/var/local/testrunner/logs" is the mounted directory. The changes made to this directory after VOLUME instruction will apply on the mounted directory and not the actual container filesystem.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone **experiencing this issue without volumes**, I found a convoluted work around.

## Problem:

With a simple Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN useradd -m -d /home/new_user new_user
COPY test_file.txt /home/new_user
RUN chown -R new_user:new_user /home/new_user
CMD ls -RFlag /home
```

After running:

```
echo "A file to test permissions." > test_file.txt
docker build -t chown-test -f Dockerfile .
docker run --rm -it chown-test
```

The output was:

```
/home:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 root 4096 Jun 15 21:37 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root 4096 Jun 15 21:39 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 root 4096 Jun 15 21:39 new_user/

/home/new_user:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 1 root 4096 Jun 15 21:39 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root 4096 Jun 15 21:37 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  220 Aug 31  2015 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 3771 Aug 31  2015 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  655 Jul 12  2019 .profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   28 Jun 11 19:48 test_file.txt
```

As you can see the file ownership (e.g. test_file.txt) is still associated with user `root`.

## Solution:

I found that if I used a numeric UID in the `chown` command, I could change the ownership, but only if the UID was not 1000. So I added 1 to the UID of `new_user` and then changed the ownership.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN useradd -m -d /home/new_user new_user
# change the uid of new_user to ensure it has whatever it was assigned plus 1 (e.g. if UID was 1000, now it'll be 1001)
RUN id -u new_user | awk '{print $1+1}' | xargs -I{} usermod -u {} new_user
COPY test_file.txt /home/new_user
RUN id -u new_user | xargs -I{} chown -R {}:{} /home/new_user
CMD ls -RFlag /home
```

After running:

```
echo "A file to test permissions." > test_file.txt
docker build -t chown-test -f Dockerfile .
docker run --rm -it chown-test
```

The output was:

```
/home:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 root 4096 Jun 15 21:37 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root 4096 Jun 15 21:37 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 1001 4096 Jun 15 21:37 new_user/

/home/new_user:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 1 1001 4096 Jun 15 21:37 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root 4096 Jun 15 21:37 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001  220 Aug 31  2015 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 3771 Aug 31  2015 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001  655 Jul 12  2019 .profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001   28 Jun 11 19:48 test_file.txt
```

I'm not sure why I was having this issue in the first place.  However, since it appears others have had this issue, I thought I'd post my workaround.  My use case was creating a docker container that served a jupyter notebook. I created a non-root user to serve the notebook.

Comment: Manually modifying the UID with `usermod` file is an ugly hack. You can specify the UID at creation with `useradd -u 1001`

Comment: You're right, it is a "hack", which is one of the reasons why I described this as "convoluted" in the first place.  The reason, I used `usermod` was because I couldn't be certain that 1001 would always be available.  Imagine if the author of the Dockerfile was adding multiple new users.  This may avoid the problem altogether, but I didn't do enough testing to be sure.  I'd be careful bandying about the term "ugly", it feels less constructive and more like a violation of the [be nice principle](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: The same basically holds for the user name; what if `new_user` already exists? But you have explained it well enough that any competent reader should probably be able to sort out these corner cases.

Comment: @tripleee I thought about editing the answer in response to your initial comment, but didn't because I settled on the same opinion as you, i.e. "any competent reader should probably be able to sort out these corner cases." I figured, between the hack I offered and your comment, readers would have two options.  Thanks again.  

I just wish I could offer a deeper explanation for why `chown` wasn't working in the first place.

Comment: If you have also been losing your hair over this recently (Aug 2023), take a look at this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/+bug/2029523

Comment: Thank you very much, @Damien. We stumbled across this bug when we made another change to our build pipeline and it caused us a tremendous amount of issues in the past week.
(I even reset my password just to upvote your comment)

Comment: this doesnt seem to work on docker-desktop

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, `chown` does not work when mounting to root (`VOLUME /test`). Use a non-root location (`VOLUME /var/test`).

Comment: This! Solved it for me despite using COPY instead of VOLUME.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using volumen, you can set permission after running, like this:

```
docker exec -u 0 my-container chmod -R 700 /my/path
docker exec -u 0 my-container chown -R my-non-user-root /my/path
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Alpine Linux users**, I had to do `chown -R root .` in the workspace I was trying to own. This had to be done in the `CMD` of the dockerfile, as I believe the volume mounts may overwrite files when mounting