# Dockerized emacs not loading extensions

Tags: emacs, docker

I'm experimenting with Dockerizing some GUI applications after being inspired by an [excellent blog post on the topic](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/). I'm working on getting [spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) up and running, because spacemacs is awesome. But for some reason Docker doesn't seem to be cloning the spacemacs repo as expected.

My Dockerfile is:

```
# Run spacemacs in a contianer
#
# sudo docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY garry-cairns/spacemacs
#
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Garry Cairns
ENV REFRESHED_AT 2015-06-29

# get base components
RUN ["apt-get", "-y", "install", "emacs", "git"]

# move into our working directory
# ADD must be after chown see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26145444/1281947
RUN ["groupadd", "spacemacs"]
RUN ["useradd", "spacemacs", "-s", "/bin/bash", "-m", "-g", "spacemacs", "-G", "spacemacs"]
ENV HOME /home/spacemacs
WORKDIR /home/spacemacs
RUN ["chown", "-R", "spacemacs:spacemacs", "/home/spacemacs"]

# install emacs and spacemacs extensions
RUN ["git", "clone", "--recursive", "https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs", "~/.emacs.d"]

# add local setup
ADD ./spacemacs .spacemacs

USER spacemacs:spacemacs
ENTRYPOINT ["emacs"]
```

As it says in the comment at the top of the file I run that with:

```
sudo docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY --name spacemacs garry-cairns/spacemacs
```

That brings up a stock emacs on my display. If I look for files I can see a `.emacs.d` directory in `~/emacs` but there's nothing in it hence no spacemacs extensions.

I've also tried just `ADD`ing my own `.emacs.d` right where I add the `.spacemacs` file. Interestingly that brings up the spacemacs start screen I'd expect, with my preferred theme, but evil-mode isn't running. I expect other modes probably aren't running either but they're much harder to check than evil mode.

Can anyone suggest what more I could do to get this working?

Comment: I think the issue is because docker is interpreting "~/.emacs.d" literally. using "/home/spacemacs/.emacs.d" works fine for me!

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: @cryss I'm afraid not. In the end real work got in the way and I abandoned this.