# Jupyter Notebook on Docker opens in "read-only" mode, how to enable saving changes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, containers, jupyter

I am creating and starting a container using the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files I provided below. My goal is to use Jupyter Notebook on Docker containers. However, when I open the notebook in my browser, it opens in "read-only" mode, which means that any changes I make are not being saved.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM jupyter/tensorflow-notebook
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./notebooks ./notebooks
RUN chmod -R 777 /app
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: tensorf-notebook
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    read_only: false
    command: jupyter notebook --allow-root --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --NotebookApp.password='sha1:...'
```

**h ttp://localhost:8888/notebooks/notebooks/app.ipynb:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing os that the Docker container is an isolated copy of your Jupyter environment. It may write to its workdir, but that is not mapped to your working directory on your local machine.

The best way to achieve what you want to do is mounting the current working directory of your host machine to the Docket container, so that the /app directory to which the container writes will be linked with the current working directory on your own machine, in which the original files reside (*.ipynb, data, etc.).

This basically requires an additional parameter when running the Docker container, like so

```
docker run -v "${PWD}":/home/username/jupyterdir nameofimage
```

You have to run this command from within the directory with your notebooks and data, and the path in the command must be the working directory of Jupyter **from within the Docker container** (i.e. inside the image).

One additional caveat: On OSX/Docker Desktop and maybe Windows, this should work without additional measures. On Linux, you may need to make sure that the user ID set by the Docker container matches your user ID on the host machine.

Ser the -v parameter in the Docker documentation for details.

Answer (score -1):

Before changing the permissions, I acquired root access and resolved the issue. I edited the Dockerfile as follows:

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM jupyter/tensorflow-notebook
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
USER root
RUN chmod -R 777 /app
```

`USER root`: Switches the user to root within the container, granting root access.

`RUN chmod -R 777 /app`: Changes the permissions of the /app directory and its contents to allow read, write, and execute access for all users.

To create a new container by rebuilding the images:

```
docker compose up -d --build
```

Comment: `chmod 777` is, to put it delicately, not a best practice and you should not endorse it here.

Comment: What other methods can you suggest then?

Comment: Can you `docker run -u` the container with a numeric user ID that matches the user owning the host directory, or use one of the other approaches from [Docker-compose set user and group on mounted volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462189/docker-compose-set-user-and-group-on-mounted-volume)?

Comment: One thing that's not obvious either here or from that question is that the volume mount hides the ownership and permissions of the image directory, so the `RUN chmod 0777` doesn't even have an effect; you could see this with `docker-compose run app ls -ld /app`.  The `USER root` is the actual important part of this answer.